# A way to search for journals that are in a similar area to a given journal

Tags: journals, online-resource

Does anyone know a website or application that can be used to search for similar journals to a given journal?

There are many ways to search for journals based on keywords from your title or abstract, e.g. [Journal / Author Name Estimator (JANE)](https://jane.biosemantics.org/), but I can't find anything that will give all journals in a similar field to one you already know about.

Many thanks if anybody knows of a tool like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The [Scimago Journal Rank](https://www.scimagojr.com) does this reasonably well for journals in specialized fields ([example](https://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?category=3104&type=j)). However, if you look at a given journal ([example](https://www.scimagojr.com/journalsearch.php?q=17853&tip=sid&clean=0)) there can be many subject areas listed, so unfortunately it isn't a great tool for finding similar journals that cover multiple areas.

Just don't rely too much on such lists. They're good for exploring what's out there, but the [various scores](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/126931/17254) it provides should be taken with a grain of salt. And as D.W. wrote in [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/10395/17254),

> There is no shortcut. If you are knowledgeable about your field, a random webpage is not going to know your field better than you do. If you are not knowledgeable about your field, then the first thing you need to do is to fix that.

Comment: In particular, if you know the main research groups working in a given field, you can look at where their papers are published to find relevant journals.

Comment: Thanks the fields on the scimago website are perfect for what I am after. I understand the scores are fairly meh, but it's good to be able to get a good idea of what journals are published in a certain area.

With regards to the highlighted point. I am not knowledgeable in a certain field, and therefore I don't know about many journals posted in said area. I want to find be aware of the relevant literature, to become more knowledgeable. Being able to find relevant literature without being an expert is important, and sites like that can help in this manner.